# Did XAML caching behavior change in Windows 8.1 Preview

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a repeating XAML animation of multiple scaling arrows which update several times per second which has worked fine on Silverlight, Win8, WinPhone7, and WinPhone8.  But now, with the Windows 8.1 Preview I'm getting the following unexpected behavior:

1. Initial display of the animated arrows is correct through one cycle of all scaled sizes.
2. On the second and subsequent repetitions of the animation, the arrows are scaled to the correct size, **but are all apparently scaled up versions of a low rez, cached bitmap** of the arrow.  This looks horrible.
3. If I switch apps and return to my app, the initial display is correct and then reverts to the bad low-rez version (in other words behaviors 1 and 2 repeat).

I would assume this is due to some change in UIElement caching behavior in Win8.1 Preview, but can't find any documentation of a change in this area.

UiElement.CacheMode would seem a likely candidate to effect a fix, but I'd like to know if this behavior is by design or will require code changes for the final release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:  A work around to the bug/feature in Windows 8.1 Preview XAML is adding the following to the **TransformGroup** associated with the problematic UIElement:

```
rotateGroup.CacheMode = null;
```

I have absolutely no idea why this change was necessary.  One further description of the problem before the above hack was added:

*If the arrow resizing changes incrementally by a small amount, then the bug appears.  If the scale factor changes in larger jumps, then the bug goes away and the arrows display correctly.*